# why vector is always slower than C array, at least in this case?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to find all the primes not greater than `n` using the Eratosthenes'Sieve algorithm, and I have the following codes, with the sieve implemented in vector and C array, I have found that almost during all the time, C array is always faster.

Using vector:

```
int countPrimes_vector(int n) {                  
    int res = 0; 
    vector<char>bitmap(n);
    memset(&bitmap[0], '1', bitmap.size() * sizeof( bitmap[0]));
    //vector<bool>bitmap(n, true); Using this one is even slower!!

    for (int i = 2; i<n; ++i){

        if(bitmap[i]=='1')++res;
        if(sqrt(n)>i)
        {
             for(int j = i*i; j < n; j += i) bitmap[j] = '0';
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Using C array:

```
int countPrimes_array(int n) {  

    int res = 0; 
    bool * bitmap = new bool[n];
    memset(bitmap, true, sizeof(bool) * n);
    for (int i = 2; i<n; ++i){

        if(bitmap[i])++res;
        if(sqrt(n)>i)
        {
             for(int j = i*i; j < n; j += i) bitmap[j] = false;
        }
    }
    delete []bitmap;
    return res;
}
```

The test code:

```
clock_t t;
t = clock();
int a;
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)a = countPrimes_vector(8000000); 
t = clock() - t;
cout<<"time for vector = "<<t<<endl;

t = clock();
int b;
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)b = countPrimes_array(8000000); 
t = clock() - t;
cout<<"time for array = "<<t<<endl;
```

The output:

```
 time for vector = 32460000
 time for array = 29840000
```

I have tested many times, and C array is always faster. What's the reason behind it?

I often heard that the performance for `vector` and C array is the same, `vector` should be always used for being a standard container. Is this statement true, or at least generally speaking ? In what cases C array should be preferred?

**EDIT:**

As the following comments suggest, after turning on optimization `-O2` or `-O3` (originally it was compiled with `g++ test.cpp`), the time difference between `vector` and C array is no longer valid, in some occasions `vector` is faster than C array.

Comment: No data structure can't beat array, it is simple as it is?

Comment: What compiler options did you compile with? Optimization settings are quite important for these kinds of questions. Also I'd argue the minor (it really isn't much) performance drop you experience is pretty small for the additional safety and ease of use you get.

Comment: @Steephen but `std::vector` **is** a dynamic array.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl, compiled with default using g++:  `g++ test.cpp`, g++ version is 4.6.1.

Comment: use `-O2`... and observe the result :)

Comment: The codes are not equivalent. In one case you use the value 49 to denote logical True, and 48 to denote false. In the other case you use 1 and compare it to 0. Why on Earth do you do this.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf comparison with zero will be faster than 1, am I right?

Comment: @Steephen: I gather a smart compiler can optimize that away if one but *asks* it to do so.

Comment: Just a quick check: if you do `char *bmp=&bitmap[0];` before the loop and inside use `bmp` instead of `bitmap` does it get as fast? Because I saw many times g++ (even recent-ish versions) failing to realize that the array cannot be reallocated inside the loop, and thus reloading the data pointer from the stack at each iteration. Also, there are many cases where the compiler simply cannot prove it (typically if you get the vector as a reference parameter and call other stuff), so often you have to resort to this trick.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, because `vector<bool>` is not a standard container, and in `vector<int>`, the `sizeof(int)` is 4.

Comment: Doing performance testing without optimizations enabled is largely pointless, since you are testing an executable that was generated to be easy to debug, rather than one that was intended to run at maximum efficiency.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, compile with `g++ -O2 test.cpp`,  the result is `time for vector = 28360000
time for array = 27720000`

Comment: A significant difference I see is the value-initialization of **every** element in the vector, *then* the worthless `memset`. The former of those is not an overhead your dynamic array of `bool` undergoes.

Comment: @Allanqunzi: I think you mean that `vector<bool>`'s buffer is not guaranteed to be a raw array of `bool`. If so then that's correct so far. But I didn't ask about that, I asked about why on Earth you're using values 48 and 49.

Comment: @Allanqunzi surprisingly without any commandline flags I get `time for vector = 7225481 time for array = 6330749` and compiled with `-O2` I get **`time for vector = 1860333 time for array = 1947682`** so vector is faster than array which seems very unlikely, so I guess they are about the same and the difference is from whatever else is running on my system. Ofc that depends on my system though. **Edit: that's on gcc 5.1**

Comment: Try swapping the order of your two tests. Often in "benchmarks" like this, the second one runs faster because of cacheing or something.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, like I commented, `vector<bool>` is even slower. For your question, I didn't have a better solution. What do you suggest I should compare?

Comment: @Allanqunzi: Use `vector<char>` as you're doing, but (1) declare it as `vector<char>bitmap(n, true);`, and (2) remove the `memset`, and (3) remove the `=='1'` and (4) replace `0` with `false`. I think that covers it. Essentially, compare equivalent codes.

Comment: You should really use the same values in both cases... currently one case uses `1` and `0` and the other uses `'1'` and `'0'`. In fact it would be preferable to start off with zero-initialized, and set `1` for composite numbers

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf:  BTW, the values 48 and 49 are the *ASCII* codes for `'0'` and `'1'`.  The OP may not know the difference between textual representation and internal representation. :-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Thank you. I know what the values are. I referred to the numerical values for the benefit of the OP.

Comment: This debate convinces me they no longer teach programming in college, or that everyone is now a self-taught programmer with no understanding of fundamentals.

Comment: @CareyGregory or that college programming courses are mostly dreadful

Comment: @MattMcNabb Mine weren't dreadful, just difficult and full of information that has remained useful throughout my entire career. Like why I wouldn't even bother asking this question, for example.

Comment: My results after making the changes I suggested, and using `-O3`: `time for array = 7551` `time for vector = 7445`.  Each number varies by 2%-ish per run though, so this is within the margin of error.

Comment: Just for the sake of having some actual verifiable numbers here, [compiled using g++ 5.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19efa76252416f09) the vector is about the same/slightly faster (probably random). [Compiled using clang++ 3.6](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52314d265977f21d) clang is seemingly able to fully optimize out your little benchmark in the array case.

Comment: [Get ready to have your mind blown](http://ideone.com/wtswU4)

Comment: @CareyGregory, what fundamentals I failed to understand here?  Why one can not be a self-taught programmer?

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl, thanks for your testing, after using optimization `-O2`, I also get vector is faster than array in some occasions. If possible, can you explain to me why optimization can make a difference? And why when comparing one should turn on the optimization?

Comment: @Allanqunzi mainly array indexing being builtin versus array being a templated class with overloaded index operator. Function calls (especially on templates) like the index operator often don't get inlined without sufficient optimization. Also I think the random difference is pretty much random system load from other programs running.

Comment: @Allanqunzi Another difference is that on some implementations `vector::operator[]` will perform range checking on builds that are not optimized, and you would pay a huge penalty for that on performance tests.

Comment: I view unoptimized code as deliberately crippled code to facilitate debugging. In my tests with optimization and after fixing the vector code ala @kfsone's answer vector is identical to dynamic array. I expect the compiler to optimize away everything vector adds by way of function calls.

Comment: Also using `std::vector<bool>bitmap(n, true);` like @AndyG did makes the vector more than 3 times faster in my tests.

Comment: there is the little problem that the posted algorithm returns a count that 1 too large.

Comment: regarding to optimize or not to optimize...  in large/complex projects, especially projects that heavily access the hardware, as do many real-time embedded projects, optimization will result in a executable that fails, where the un-optimized code worked 'perfectly'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your comparisons contain inconsistencies which would explain the differences, and another factor could be the result of compiling without sufficient optimization. Some implementations have a lot of additional code in the debug builds of STL, for instance MSVC does bounds checking on vector element accesses that produce a significant reduction in speed in debug builds.

The following code shows a MUCH closer performance between the two, and the difference is probably just a lack of samples (ideone has a timeout limit of 5s).

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>

int countPrimes_vector(int n) {  
    int res = 0; 
    std::vector<bool> bitmap(n, true);
    for (int i = 2; i<n; ++i){
        if(bitmap[i])
          ++res;
        if(sqrt(n)>i)
        {
             for(int j = i*i; j < n; j += i) bitmap[j] = false;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int countPrimes_carray(int n) {  
    int res = 0; 
    bool* bitmap = new bool[n];
    memset(bitmap, true, sizeof(bool) * n);
    for (int i = 2; i<n; ++i){

        if(bitmap[i])++res;
        if(sqrt(n)>i)
        {
             for(int j = i*i; j < n; j += i) bitmap[j] = false;
        }
    }
    delete []bitmap;
    return res;
}

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(const char* description, int (*fn)(int))
{
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds;

    auto start = clock::now();

    int a;
    for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)
        a = countPrimes_vector(8000000); 

    auto end = clock::now();
    auto diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(end - start);

    std::cout << "time for " << description << " = " << diff.count() << "ms\n";
}

int main()
{
    test("carray", countPrimes_carray);
    test("vector", countPrimes_vector);
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/0Y9gQx

```
time for carray = 2251ms
time for vector = 2254ms
```

Although on some runs the carray was 1-2 ms slower. Again, that's insufficient samples on a shared resource.

--- EDIT ---

In your main comments you ask "why optimization can make a difference".

```
std::vector<bool> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
bool b[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

We have two "array"s of 3 elements, so consider the following:

```
v[10]; // illegal!
b[10]; // illegal!
```

Debug versions of STL can often catch this during run time (and with some scenarios, compile time). The array access may just result in bad data or a crash.

Additionally, the STL is implemented using many small member-function calls to things like `size()`, and because `vector` is a class, `[]` is actually facaded through a function call (`operator[]`).

The compiler can eliminate many of these, but that's optimization. If you don't optimize, then something like

```
std::vector<int> v;
v[10];
```

does something roughly like:

```
int* data() { return M_.data_; }

v.operator[](size_t idx = 10) {
    if (idx >= this->size()) {
        raise exception("invalid [] access");
    }
    return *(data() + idx);
}
```

and even though data is an "inlinable" function, to make debugging easier, the unoptimized code leaves it as this. When you build with optimization, the compiler recognizes that the implementation of these functions are so trivial it can just substitute their implementations into the call sites, and it quickly winds up simplifying all of the above to a more array-access like operation.

For example, in the above case, it may first reduce `operator[]` to

```
v.operator[](size_t idx = 10) {
    if (idx >= this->size()) {
        raise exception("invalid [] access");
    }
    return *(M_.data_ + idx);
}
```

And since compiling without debugging probably removes the bounds check, it becomes

```
v.operator[](size_t idx = 10) {
    return *(M_.data_ + idx);
}
```

so now the inliner can reduce

```
x = v[1];
```

to

```
x = *(v.M_.data_ + 1); // comparable to v.M_.data_[1];
```

There *is* a tiny penalty. The c-array involves the data block in memory and a single local variable that fits into a register that points to the block, your references are directly relative to that:

With a vector, though, you have the vector object which is a pointer to the data, a size and a capacity variable:

```
vector<T>  // pseudo code
{
    T* ptr;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
}
```

If you were counting machine instructions, the vector will have 3 variables to initialize, and manage.

When you write

```
x = v[1];
```

given the above approximation of vector, you are saying something along the lines of:

```
T* ptr = v.data();
x = ptr[1];
```

but the compiler is usually smart enough when building with optimization to recognize that it can do the first line before the loop, but this tends to cost a register.

```
T* ptr = v.data(); // in debug, function call, otherwise inlined.
for ... {
    x = ptr[1];
}
```

So you're probably looking at a handful more machine instructions per iteration of your test function, or on a modern processor, maybe a nanosecond or two of extra wall time.

Comment: Just to add a datapoint: with g++4.9 and 10 successive tests, I get that the difference between the mean times is within 0.01 standard deviations, so we are definitely talking about random fluctuations.

Comment: `vector<bool>` is even more different than your explanation indicates.  It doesn't even have a `data()` member function.  In particular, the paragraph where you say "When you write

`x = vector_bools[1];`

you are actually saying:

`bools* bools_ptr = vector_bools.data();
x = bools_ptr[1];`" is totally bogus

Comment: Fair point, Ben, I'll try to rectify and/or indicate I'm being approximate.

Comment: @BenVoigt Adapted to `int` and clearer indication that I'm aproximating.